# i am getting a null object reference error in android studio while animating a image

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void click(View view) {
        ImageView bart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.bart);
        bart.animate().alpha(0);
    }
}
```

This is the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator android.widget.ImageView.animate()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from:

```
R.drawable.bart
```

in to:

```
R.id.bart
```

And are you sure that in `onCreate()` you call `setContentView()` method (which inflates layout)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are referencing to a `drawable id` and not a `view id`.
Use `R.id` for views, `R.drawable` is for drawable resource.